# Image floating over parent div

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to put an (hover) image on top of its parent div. I use an older version of www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/magnify.html, though a bit modified to my needs.

I found a way to achieve what I want earlier in a previous site => http://www.keurslagergeertenkristel.be/. In the center you'll see a picture containing a black/white photograph at left and some pink/bordeaux tints and some text. If you hover with cursor, the picture will enlarge so you can see it properly (I know there might be an issues with small screen resolutions, but thats not the problem right now)

I'm trying to do the same thing again in a new site I'm building, but I can't get it to work :s The image **always** stays in its parent div.
You can check out here => http://www.vermeulenklasseslager.be/NEW/.

The CSS for the images for both websites is identical, so it must be something with the parent div I guess, but I can't see it.

I tried a lot of variations, using display:block, position:relative (for parent div), overflow:hidden and auto, adding extra divs or spans, adding z-index...

**UPDATE: I JUST DISCOVERED THE PROBLEM ONLY HAPPENS IN IE11.** (wich makes I understand even less why, because the first website works in all browsers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in ie 10/11 it crops the large image because of a border-radius property on the content div. The solution is to remove overflow:hidden and clear this container with standard clearfix:

```
#content:before, 
#content:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
#content:after {
  clear: both;
}
#content {
  zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, removing overflow:hidden did the trick! I did not need other code. Besides, on my other site I also used border-radius and there it wasn't a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution to that is:

> position : fixed

Comment: It helped! Although I still don't understand why it was working on the first website and not on the new with the same code.
Now, when I hover, the Original smaller picture falls a few pixels down, and goes back up when mouse leaves. Can this be prevented?

Comment: UPDATE: check first post